# Not getting Hours and Minutes correctly using javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript

Added javascript code for displaying time and hours for a ceremony.Days are Coming correctly but hours,Minutes are not working correctly.This was the code i have used.

```js
var deadline = new Date("May 1, 2019 03:30:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var t = deadline - now;
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = seconds;
  if (t < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "TIME UP";
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = '0';
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="days" id="day"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="hours" id="hour"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="minutes" id="minute"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="seconds" id="second"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Exact time should come like this `41 days 984 hours 59040 minutes`

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/zrvdt4fy/4/

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @SergeK. the link which you shared was displaying the date i need countdown timer

Comment: @user9131066 Given link points you towards the right directions to easily achieveyour goalm this is not a copy/paste answer.

Comment: @cale_b if the change the id in javascript code it is getting blank not getting hours or minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the modulo operation:

```js
var deadline = new Date("May 1, 2019 03:30:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var t = deadline - now;
  
  // change is happening from here...
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor(t / 1000);
  // to here
  
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days;
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = seconds;
  if (t < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "TIME UP";
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = '0';
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="days" id="day"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="hours" id="hour"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="minutes" id="minute"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timerdays">
    <span class="seconds" id="second"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working getting blank fields instead  of timer

Comment: What? No it doesnt